# What's wrong with my for loop?Printing certain properties of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
// Type some JavaScript code here.
var destinationAirport;
var stops;
window.routesResponse = function(routes)
{
     // YOUR CODE
    for(i=0;i<routes.length;i++)
    {
         routesArray=routes[i]
         destinationAiport=routesArray.destinationAirport
         stops=routesArray.stops
         console.log(destinationAirport,stops)
    }


}


// Make the API request:
var url = "https://eng1003.monash/OpenFlights/routes/?      airline=QF&sourceAirport=MEL&callback=routesResponse";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

So I got this route API that has the following endpoints (i.e., URLs that can be called for different information). Routes: https://eng1003.monash/OpenFlights/routes/?airline=airlineCode&sourceAirport=airportCode&callback=funcName Returns an array of route information objects for all flights from airportCode operated by airlineCode. Requires the following parameters: airline is an airline code, such as “QF” for QANTAS or “EK” for Emirates. sourceAirport is an airport code, such as “MEL” for Tullamarine or “LAX” for Los Angeles. callback is the JSONP callback function, if using JSONP. I want to make a request to this API from JavaScript and display the results. The routesResponse function iterates over each route in the routes array and prints the destinationAirport and number of stops (to the usual outputArea div).These are my codes but when I publish them the stops and destination airport does not display?

Comment: are you sure it have to be `destinationAirport`. not `routes[i].destinationAirport`?

Comment: Change this `destinationAiport=routes[destinationAirport]` to `destinationAiport=routes[i]`.. And this line too `stops=routes[stops]`.. I think it will always be empty..

Comment: I've edited it but t still doesn't work?

Comment: Your URL (with the spaces removed) returns `funcName([]);`. As you can see, it is expecting to call a function named `funcName` (which you passed in as part of the URL), and it passes that function an empty array. You do not have a function called `funcName`, so nothing will be called. And if you did have a function with that name, it would receive an empty array, so your `for` loop would be executed exactly zero times. If you look in the JavaScript console, do you not see an error about the undefined function?

Comment: What you really need to learn here is how to debug JavaScript code. Every browser has developer tools built in. For example, if you use Chrome, search for "chrome devtools" to find some excellent resources on how to debug your code. Once you learn how to debug, you will have a much better time of it - you will be able to solve your own problems without relying on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Then how do I get the URL  to execute my for loop?